# Prompting user for infinite values without an array

Tags: c

I know this isn't necessarily a difficult coding question but I am just unsure where to start due to its parameters and any help would be appreciated.
I have been asked to

> Write a short program that will ask the user to enter a sequence of
>   positive integer values (ending with zero or any negative value) and
>   print out the number of values entered and the largest value entered.
>   **DO NOT USE ARRAYS**

Comment: How would you do this with a piece of paper and a pencil?

Comment: Most important detail: No one asked for the full list of numbers that were entered.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some pseudocode:

```
cnt := 0
max := smallest possible integer
while True:
    Get one input from user.
    Break if the input is zero or not positive.
    cnt := cnt + 1
    if current input > max, then max := current input

Print cnt.
Print max.
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the Solution* **without Arrays**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int max=0,count=0;
  int number=-1;
  while(1){
      printf("Enter a Number , to stop press 0\n");
      scanf("%d",&number);
       if(number ==0)
        break;
      count++;
      if (number>=max){
        max=number;
      }
  }
  printf("The Largest number is %d\n",max);
  printf("Number of element you entered id %d",count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program has undefined behaviour. I let you find our by yourself why.

Comment: i didn't get that.

Comment: Still undefined behaviour after your edit. BTW: Empty parameter list is a deprecated feature. In general providing a complete working solution for homework assignments spoils the learning opportunity.

Comment: @DinethSGimhana hint: look closesly at the `number` variable.

Comment: @Gerhardh ... unless OP provided at least their attempt, so that the answer can point out the mistakes. (but that's not the case)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni No attempt shown would be even more reason not to show a full solution but only point to some starting point.

Comment: @DinethSGimhana UB has gone now, but still you should't post the full solution

Comment: The point of homework assignments is to try and learn, not to ask other people for the solution. If that comes as a surprise, you could have a look at this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions